# On the Double-Slit Experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, foundations, quantum-foundations

In the double slit experiment, a source of particles is pointed towards a wall with two thin slits, the state of the particle before a dot appears on the screen is represented by a linear superposition of all locations. I have two questions:

- What is the probability that a dot will appear on the screen in a time $t$ after the source is on?
- What physical process is producing the dot on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know when the particle is emitted and what its velocity is, you may predict when it impacts the screen. However, the Uncertainty Principle comes into play. If the emitted wave packet is large, you can't tell when it was emitted precisely. If it's too small, the momentum spread will wash out your interference pattern (and may affect the time of flight).

The "dot" represents an absorption event. For experiments with photons or charged particles, it's usually some sort of ionization process. The important thing is that it's irreversible: you can't recover the original particle state after the absorption. You cannot describe such an irreversible process using reversible mathematics (such as a Hamiltonian).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the incoming radiation / particle stream can be assigned velocity, so time of impact is time of emission plus duration of travel, that is, distance divided by velocity. This is only rough estimate, because different particles will arrive at random destinations, at slightly different times.

Yes, in case of light and electrons, it is electromagnetic interaction.

Comment: 1) You can't assign velocity to the incoming radiation, in the momentum space the radiation is in a linear superposition of states, not a definite momentum state.
2) What is the interaction Hamiltonian? How can you prove that the interaction caused the dot to appear?

Comment: 1) to get a nice simple textbook interference pattern, the radiation can be filtered to contain a narrow band of frequencies 2) there are many standard options, minimal coupling, or dipole interaction Hamiltonian can be used. We can't prove the interaction as modeled by the Schroedinger equation with mentioned Hamiltonian causes *dots* to appear - the mathematics only gives a smooth psi function that is similar to smoothed image of the actual pattern dots; it does not predict any dots. We *know* the dots appear and we *believe* this is due to EM interaction with the macroscopic screen.